# Is there a way to trigger pipeline using Azure Artifacts in YML?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When defining a GUI release I can make it be triggered by an Azure Artifact, is there a way to replicate this for pipelines in YML?

I am building in one AZDO tenant, pushing universal packages to another tenant, where the release definitions will be defined, I'm hoping this can be in YAML. But I don't see an obvious way to do this at the moment?

I see there is a design document that makes mention of packages, but no further details are provided

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-resources.md

Cheers

Edit-
[image]

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue based Sudarshan_SMD`s answer? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hey, @LeoLiu-MSFT, neither of the posted answers answer my question. Our scenario is different and multistage pipelines nor build completion triggers are relevant

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would mind share some more info about your request, so that we can clear what you want?

Comment: Hey @LeoLiu-MSFT, I have added a screenshot into the question. Essentially the ability to trigger a pipeline on a artifact push

Comment: Hey @LeoLiu-MSFT, do you know if there has been any progress on this internally on porting the feature from GUI pipelines to YAML?

Comment: I have created a feature request on dev community - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Trigger-Multistage-YML-through-push-of-n/1397445

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to trigger pipeline using Azure Artifacts in YML?-But I don't see an obvious way to do this at the moment?

Yes, Yes. You are right !

That because the content in this document are speculative, designs, and **future features**.

If you check the upper level of design document you provided, there is a state:

[Azure Pipelines YAML - Design Docs](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/tree/master/design)

> The design docs within this repo are created at different times during
>   the development of Azure Pipelines, to support collaborative
>   contributions to the design process. Designs documents are for,
>
> - features considered for implementation but never implemented
> - already implemented features
> - **future ideas for features**
>
> The design docs in this repo may **not** represent the current state
>   of an Azure Pipelines feature.

When you check the officially release document [YAML schema reference-Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources), it only list:

```
resources:
  pipelines: [ pipeline ]  
  repositories: [ repository ]
  containers: [ container ]
```

So, Azure Artifacts source in YAML should be a future feature at this moment. Hope MS can achieve it one day earlier.

Hope this answer clear your question.

Answer (score 0):

Build completion triggers are not yet supported in YAML syntax. After you create your YAML build pipeline, you can use the classic editor to specify a build completion trigger.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-completion-triggers

Though i would suggest you to use below mechanism to trigger the release:

- Resource triggers

  Resources trigger will be helpful in below scenario:

  - I would like to trigger my pipeline when an artifact is published by ‘Helm-CI’ pipeline that ran on releases/* branch.
  - I would like to trigger my pipeline when an artifact is published and tested as part of Helm-CI pipeline and tagged as 'Production'.
  - I would like to trigger my pipeline when ‘TFS-Update’ pipeline has completed ‘Ring2’ stage so that I can run some diagnostics.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md

- Webhook triggers
  At the end of the CI piepleing , you can add a task to hit webhook url which can trigger your CD is one way.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multi-stage pipeline to achieve this.
One stage would include a task that will push your artifacts to the feed. The next stage will contain other jobs that you want to be executed after pushing the Artifacts.

eg:

```
stages:
#Stage for preparing the Artifact    
   - stage: prepare
      jobs:
       - job: prepare
      pool:
          vmImage: xx        
      steps:
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            pathToPublish: xx
            artifactName: xx

# Next stage in your pipeline
- stage: build
  dependsOn: prepare
  jobs:
  steps:
    - task: xx
```

Note that the second stage *build* **dependsOn** the stage *prepare*.

ps: Multi-Stage pipeline is currently under preview. If you enable it from the preview feature, you will also be able to see a nice visual representation of the stages.