# YAML Release pipeline - Trigger on new Universal Package?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a couple of Release Pipelines (GUI) that are triggered on new Universal Packages.
We have been using YAML for CI builds, and recently I discovered that Release stages can be defined in YAML as well.

The only issue I found is that I can't find a way to trigger this Release-YAML-pipeline on new arrival of a Universal Package in a Feed, like you can in the GUI Release pipelines.

The only option seems to be a Build Completion trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep, for now that would be the only option. basically it would trigger right after the build. I think they recently added approval gates. that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I had a similar question, there does appear to be some design documentation around the idea of triggering on packages, but nothing firm yet

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58974190/4158021